# C++ Help about ZeroMemory

Tags: c++, winapi, char

I defined my char as usual, although I named it `buf`. I keep getting an error:

> argument of type 'char' is incompatible with parameter of type 'void*'

If I set `buf` to `void*`, it won't be able to pass in 4096 as a parameter.

So, how do I get around this? Has anyone run into a problem like this before?

```
    char buf{4096};
    string userinput;
    do
    {
        cout << "> " << endl;
        getline(cin, userinput);


        if (userinput.size() > 0) // make sure the user typed something in  
        {
            int SendResult = send(sock, userinput.c_str, userinput.size() + 1, 0);
            if (SendResult != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
                int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
                if (bytesReceived > 0)
                {
                    cout << "SERVER" << string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << 
endl;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `char buf{4096}` should probably be `char buf[4096]`. You've created a single character buffer and are trying to populate it with the value 4096.

Comment: @tadman, Likely the [winapi function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @chris Good catch. The `SendResult` naming convention threw me off.

Comment: `char buf{4096}` declares one `char` with the value `4096`.  You want `char buf[4096]`

Comment: @MilesBudnek not that 4096 will ever fit on "boring" platforms with 8 bit chars... `buf` will probably be 0 an almost any of those.

Comment: [This code will not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79a7f3d9e2b8e365).

Answer (score 5):

The problem is likely this definition:

```
char buf{4096};
```

Which is roughly equivalent to:

```
char buf = 4096;
```

Which is a single character, not a character array buffer. To fix this:

```
char buf[4096];
```

When passing that in you may need to do:

```
ZeroMemory(&buf, 4096);
```

I'd strongly encourage you to avoid hammering out 4096 everywhere, so define a constant:

```
const SIZE_T buf_size = 4096;
char buf[buf_size];

// ...

ZeroMemory(&buf, buf_size);
```

Comment: To note, a conforming C++11 compiler will not compile this because of the narrowing in braces. (And a pre-C++11 compiler won't recognize the form of initialization.) I think it's a fair assumption that 4096 isn't a valid `char` value on Windows.

Comment: Just do `ZeroMemory(&buf, sizeof buf);`

Comment: Since `buf` is a fixed array, passing its name around is the same as passing a pointer to its first element, so you don't need the `&` at all: `ZeroMemory(buf, sizeof(buf));` On the other hand, in this example, it is not necessary to zero out `buf` at all before calling `recv()`, that is just wasted overhead.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#include <array>   

std::array<char, 4096> buf;
...    

        std::fill(buf.begin(), buf.end(), 0);
        int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf.data(), buff.size(), 0);
...
```

Comment: Granted, this is a better approach, but this does nothing to answer the question that was actually asked.  StackOverflow is a Q+A site, we are here to answer question, not rewrite code.

Comment: The question was, "So, how do I get around this?".  The answer, in my opinion, involves the use of std::array.  And no, we're not just here to answer the question.  If we were we wouldn't down-vote so many.  It's also a C++ question.  My answer was idiomatic over c-style arrays.

Comment: The question being asked is in regards to fixing the error message, not changing the semantics of the code. That is what [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is for.

Answer (score 0):

Another question is why do you need `ZeroMemory` at all. And I think what happened here is that you picked up wrong string constructor overload. Let me explain:

You have your `buf` buffer and you have your `bytesReceived` length of data, so really all you need is

```
std::string(buf, bytesReceived)
```

to construct valid string. But you have chosen

```
std::string(buf, 0, bytesReceived)
```

This overload looks like this:

> basic_string( const basic_string& other, 
>                 size_type pos, 
>                 size_type count,
>                 ..

The `buf` is implicitly converted into `std::string` at the 1st argument, but for this to work correctly your buffer needs to be null terminated, which it might or might not be. So you worked around this problem by zeroing the rest of the buffer. What do you think will happen if you get 4096 bytes of data that is not null terminated? Your workaround will not work in this case. So just use the appropriate string constructor mentioned above and you won't need to use `ZeroMemory`.

Comment: According to Remy Lebeau we must answer the specific question, not offer a better alternative.  Yea... I know.

Comment: Yes.  Your answer is excellent but it's off-topic, apparently.  It's the same reason I was downvoted below.  I'm just making a point :).

Comment: @Robinson Well, I am going to upvote your answer, I hope you will feel really bad about it, you little person

Comment: I don't feel bad about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use char **buf[4096];** instead of **buf{4096}**
use buf as an array then Fill the block of memory with zeros

by the way, do you really know what does buf{4096} do??
if you do that it means that you want to put this number 4096
which will be converted to "(`" because the buf data type is char so you have used wrong way.

```
ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);    
// Wait for client to send data
int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);
if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cerr << "Error in recv(). Quitting" << endl;
        break;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).